# Change positioning when minimazing columns (CSS)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm new to HTML and CSS and I try to do a simple website.

Here is my problem:[image]

I have 4 columns with photos in full-size, but when I minimize the browser, it gets this ugly positioning.. I want the right photo to float right, but if I set that, it will be bad when they are in full size.

My question is: Is that possible to change a component float when you minimize the browser ? I want all 4 photos to float left in full size, first one to float left and second one to float right where there is only 2 columns and when I have only one column in very small size, I want that photo to be centered.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="container panel panel-default mygallery">
<div class="panel-heading text-center"><big class="h3">Most popular</big></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class="panel panel-default mypanel">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#">
                        <h4> Mozart apartment.</h4>
                    </a><small>Nr. camere: 3</small></br>
                        <small>Pret: 200.000 <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-euro"></div></small></br>
                        <small>Suprafata: 130 m<sup>2</sup></small>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body in img-1"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
```

All 4 columns have the same code, only info is different.

And CSS:

```
.mygallery {
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}

.mypanel {
    float:left;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-style: solid;
    border: 10px;
    height: 320px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 320px;
}

.img-1 {
    background: url("MostPopular/1.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 65%;
}
```

Comment: I suggest you to use twiter bootstrap. It was designed specially for cases like this.

Comment: I'm using it, but i don`t know what classes should i use from css to help me here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible by using media queries here you can learn more about its

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

You can add specific CSS for different sizes.

You can give the different columns different style with :nth-child()

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Comment: I`ll take a look

Comment: If you create a fiddle it's much more easier to help you

Comment: also feel free to ask if you have some quesions

Answer (score 1):

You should use @media selectors for this sort of things, where you can set styling for browser width so you will have something like:

```
@media screen and (min-width:1200px) {
    //your style here
}
```

You can read more about this [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)